# A Maven plugin fails and to open an issue, I would like to explain inside how the NullPointerException encountered can appear

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

While compiling an opensource project, I encounter a problem with a `Maven` plugin that fails.
And I would like to open an issue about its problem. To be helpful to those who will search to solve it, I would like to explain how it might happen.

```
Execution default of goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.3:revision failed. (pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.3:revision:default:initialize)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.3:revision failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1380)
    at [...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.execute(GitCommitIdMojo.java:441)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 30 more
```

For that, I've red the involved line that causes the `NullPointerException` on its *Git* repository.
[The content of the line 441](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/master/maven/src/main/java/pl/project13/maven/git/GitCommitIdMojo.java) of `GitCommitIdMojo.java` is :

```java
List<MavenProject> sortedProjects =
   Optional.ofNullable(session.getProjectDependencyGraph())
       .map(graph -> graph.getSortedProjects())
       .orElseGet(() -> {
          log.warn("Maven's dependency graph is null. Assuming project is the only one executed.");
          return Collections.singletonList(session.getCurrentProject());
       });
```

But I'm not so experienced with Optional and other inline functions. And I wonder from where the `NullPointerException` is really coming. I have no way to test it in Live, so I can only guess.

1. I've checked on the source file : `session` is a required attribute. It shouldn't be null.
2. I believe that the `Optional.ofNullable(...)` protects the content inside parenthesis and that the `NullPointerException` isn't coming from here.
3. But when entering the `.orElseGet(...)` part of the expression, it might fail on `Collections.singletonList(session.getCurrentProject())` where `session.getCurrentProject()` would return null.

Am I right?
What other parts of this statement could lead to a `NullPointerException` under what conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking at the right version of the code. The maven-error refers to 4.0.3 of git-commit-id-plugin, but the code you're displaying comes from the master branch, which is at 4.0.4-SNAPSHOT.

This is [line 441 in version 4.0.3](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/96379a8a0813391d2c390f63185c6bcf66eff3ce/maven/src/main/java/pl/project13/maven/git/GitCommitIdMojo.java#L441):

List sortedProjects = session.getProjectDependencyGraph().getSortedProjects();

The NullPointer can come from any of the three parts.

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't able to find that `4.0.3` branch from its _Git_ interface  and assumed (wrongly !) that `master` was unchanged. I go to have a look if the same line still exist on `master`.

Comment: Ok it has changed between `4.0.3` and `4.0.4` in what is surely a correction of my problem. So there's no longer an issue.